# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 ao executar JAR

Tags: java

Tenho um projeto no NetBeans e tenho que passar ele para teste para outros usuários. Estou executando ele no Ubuntu 14 e executando o seguinte comando para executar o .jar:

```
java -jar "TesteTableYasc.jar"
```

Porem, ao tentar executar o arquivo .jar dá erro de versão do Java. O erro é o seguinte:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:     yasc/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Ao executar **java -version**:

```
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Ao executar **javac -version**:

```
javac 1.6.0_40
```

Como posso resolver esse erro?

Comment: Você parece estar misturando vários conceitos e partindo direto para a solução para o que você supõe ser o problema. Estou suspeitando que isso é um [problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy). Seria mais produtivo começarmos do começo: como você está executando esse JAR? Qual é o erro que você recebe?

Comment: Atualizei a questão

Comment: Execute no terminal `java -version` e `javac -version` e cole na pergunta o resultado de ambos.

Comment: Coloquei na questão as saidas dos comandos

Comment: O _build path_ da sua IDE deve estar apontando para o Java 8. Altere para o Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro problema está relacionado com a versão do java utilizado para compilar o jar. Neste caso, o jar foi compilado com a versão 1.8 e está a tentar executá-lo com uma versão inferior. Dependendo das dependências, pode compilar o jar com compatibilidade para uma versão inferior ou executar o jar com a versão 1.8 do java.

- J2SE 8 = 52
- J2SE 7 = 51
- J2SE 6.0 = 50
- J2SE 5.0 = 49
- JDK 1.4 = 48
- JDK 1.3 = 47
- JDK 1.2 = 46
- JDK 1.1 = 45

Relativamente ao tema das versões 1.6 e 1.7, o tema parece estar relacionado com facto de ter duas entradas na path. Como esta a usar o Ubuntu pode utilizar o seguinte comando para configurar a versão do java

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```